# Create controllers in ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to create dynamically controllers responsible for view of data from REST API. My idea is to use ng-repeat directive with data from service and inside it create object with ng-controller directive with parameter from ng-repeat output (The most important condition is that each one question must have its own $scope). Unfortunatelly I don't know how to pass data from service.

AngularJS service code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('App')
        .factory('questionsDataService', questionsDataService);

    questionsDataService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function questionsDataService($http) {
        return {
            getMetadata: function (taskId) {
                var metaData = $http.get('api/toDo/taskVariables/' + taskId).then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                return metaData;
            },

            getQuestionsData: function (taskId) {
                var questionsData = $http.get('api/toDo/getQuestions/' + taskId).then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                return questionsData;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: You've just bumped all of your code inside this post, which makes it really difficult to read and understand. I recommend to edit this, and include only the relevant parts here to make it stand out clearly. You can bump all the required code in a fiddle and post the link in this question.

Comment: What is that last character in your name Micha"l"? It looks like it has something going through it. I thought it was a smudge on my screen, until I scrolled and still saw it there.

Comment: Thanks for constructive answer ;) It's letter from Polish alphabet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, your title is misleading, but I will show how to get the data from the service. I don't think you need a new controller for each item in an ng-repeat, but without more info on why you are trying to do this, I can't help there.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('App')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    // you are injecting your service here, this will be whatever the string is from the .factory() call
    myController.$inject = ['$scope', 'questionsDataService'];


    // again, we are passing the service in to the controller function
    function myController($scope, questionsDataService) {

        // your service calls are returning promises
        // this will get run when the controller is initialized
        questionsDataService.getMetadata(1).then(function(data){
            // here is where you can access the returned metadata
            // save it to the scope so you can access it in the DOM
            console.log(data);
        })

        // if you want to call your service on a button click, or with some other function
        $scope.getQuestions = function (id) {
            questionsDataService.getQuestionsData(id).then(function (data) {
                // here is where you can access the returned data
                // save it to the scope so you can access it in the DOM
                console.log(data);
            })
        }

        // I added a service method that returns a string, rather than a promise
        // this will get run when the controller is initialized
        var str = questionsDataService.getServiceName();
        console.log(str);

    }
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('App')
        .factory('questionsDataService', questionsDataService);

    questionsDataService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function questionsDataService($http) {
        return {
            getMetadata: function (taskId) {
                var metaData = $http.get('api/toDo/taskVariables/' + taskId).then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                return metaData;
            },

            getQuestionsData: function (taskId) {
                var questionsData = $http.get('api/toDo/getQuestions/' + taskId).then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                return questionsData;
            },

            // adding this just to show you how to access functions that don't return promises
            getServiceName: function () {
                return "questionsDataService";
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, thank you for your reply. I know how to access to data from service in controller. My goal is to create questions (iframes with data from service) and each one of them must have individual scope. It's necessary beacuse of performance of project